# Is there a whitelist or blacklist of characters for custom sml infixes?

Tags: sml

`infix 3 ..` errors out. Which characters are allowed or not allowed for defining custom infixes? Where might I find a list online?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may infix any non-qualified identifier.

The following is from the SML 90' definition

> The following are the *reserved words* used in the Core. They may not (except =) be used as identifiers.
>
> ```
> abstype and andalso as case do datatype else
> end exception fn fun handle if in infix
> infixr let local nonfix of op open orelse
> raise rec then type val with withtype while
> ( ) [ ] { } , : ; ... _ | = => -> #
> ```

....

> An identifier is either *alphanumeric*: any sequence of letters,
>   digits or primes (') and underbars (_) starting with a letter or
>   prime, or *symbolic*: any non-empty sequence of the following
>   *symbols*:
>
> ```
> ! % & # + - / : < = > ? @ \ ~ ' ^ | *
> ```
>
> In either case, however, reserved words are excluded. This means that
>   for example # and | are not identifiers, but ## and |=| are
>   identifiers. The only exception to this rule is that the symbol =,
>   which is a reserved word, is also allowed as an identifier to stand
>   for the equality predicate.